# Truffle returning balances from a function

Tags: truffle, javascript

This maybe just a simple Javascript issue, but it's in the context of running under Truffle. I can't seem to access my object variables coming back from my function; thus the tests are failing with error about the toString being undefined.  So I added console.log code to show the values...

To avoid rewriting repetitive, code, I created this function:

```
async function GetAndShowUserBalances(description, userName, userAddr) 
{
  let balanceTokens, balanceEth 
  balanceTokens= await exchange.balanceOf(token.address, userAddr); 
  balanceEth  = await exchange.balanceOf(ETHER_ADDRESS, userAddr); 
  console.log("ShowUserBalances: " + description + " " + userName + 
                 " Ether=" + tokensRev(balanceEth) + 
                 " Tokens=" + tokensRev(balanceTokens)); 
   var result = {}; 
   result.Ether = balanceEth; 
   result.Tokens = balanceTokens; 
         console.log('============================================ START result ')
         console.log(JSON.stringify(result)) 
         console.log('============================================ END  result ')

   return result; 

}
```

The results look good as JSON in the above console.log.

Then I call it like this:

```
describe('depositing tokens', async () => {
  let result, user1Balances 
  const numTokensToDeposit = 8 

   describe('success', async () => {

      beforeEach(async() => {
          //approve this smart contract as the exchange address 
          user1Balances = GetAndShowUserBalances("before  depositToken", "user1", user1Addr) 
          await token.approve(exchange.address, tokens(numTokensToDeposit), { from: user1Addr})
          result = await exchange.depositToken(
                         token.address, tokens(numTokensToDeposit), { from: user1Addr})
          console.log("DepositTokens completed: numTokensToDeposit=" + numTokensToDeposit)
      })

      it('tracks the token deposit',async() => {
         user1Balances = GetAndShowUserBalances("after depositToken", "user1", user1Addr) 
         // check exchange token balance 
         //balance1 = await token.balanceOf(exchange.address); 
         console.log('============================================ START user1Balances ')
         console.log(JSON.stringify(user1Balances)) 
         console.log('============================================ END  user1Balances ')
         user1Balances.Tokens.toString().should.equal(tokens(numTokensToDeposit).toString()) 
         //check tokens on exchange for the user 
         //balance2 = await exchange.tokens(token.address, user1Addr)
         user1Balances.Ether.toString().should.equal(tokens(numTokensToDeposit).toString()) 
      })
```

Console display:

```
depositing tokens
      success
ShowUserBalances: before  depositToken user1 Ether=0 Tokens=0
============================================ START result
{"Ether":"0","Tokens":"0"}
============================================ END  result
DepositTokens completed: numTokensToDeposit=8
============================================ START user1Balances
{}
============================================ END  user1Balances
```

Comment: Is it possible for depositToken to have failed? The function ´GetAndShowUserBalances´ is declared async but you are not waiting for it to finish.

Comment: Function `GetAndShowUserBalances` is `async`, and so you probably want to `await` for its completion whenever you call it.

Comment: In addition to that (though not directly related to your problem), you are passing two arguments to function `balanceOf`, which AFAIK takes only one parameter.

Comment: balanceOf in my contract takes two parms, the first is the erc20Token,, the second is the user's address.  I added official answer based on both of your comments, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comments above gave answer without the syntax. Need the await in the assignment:

```
 user1Balances = await GetAndShowUserBalances("before  depositToken", "user1", user1Addr)
```